# jquery detect scroll bar position

Tags: jquery

I have a button, when scroll bar is bigger than 600, it will show, if less it will hide.

I'm not sure where is the problem, it is not working.

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop<600){$('#top').hide();}
    else{$('#top').show();}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the `scroll()` event to the window, rather than checking the scroll position once.

Try something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop < 600) {
        $('#top').hide();
    } else {
        $('#top').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe provide an example for Ben?

Comment: I did when it was a one liner, now it's a valid answer. So +1

Comment: Correct syntax is `$(window).scroll(` not document!